# How to set model value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to send a model to my backend from my frontend angular, this is how I define it in the class I want to use:

```
  documentsArray : DocumentModel
```

Now I have this method:

```
uploadFile(files: FileList | null): void {
      if(files){
        const file = files.item(0)
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload = () => {
        this.documentsArray.filename = file.name,
        this.api.saveDocument({body: 
         this.documentsArray        
        }).subscribe({
          next: data => console.log(data),
          error: error => console.log("your error: " + error)
        })
        console.log(this.documentsArray[0])
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.documentsArray))
        }
      }
    }
```

But then I try to set this part:

```
    this.documentsArray.filename = file.name,
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'filename')
```

The model only has strings. Could someone tell me my error.

Answer (score 2):

First: you need to clarify whehter `documentsArray` is really an Array.

If yes, you have to specify the index at line:

```
this.documentsArray.filename = file.name,
```

As follow:

```
this.documentsArray[0].filename = file.name,
```

Guessing you want to set the first element name

If no, please show the entire file in a online code editor, such us [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and share the link here

Answer (score 1):

documentsArray is undefined. Therefore you cant reach undefined.filename; you have to declare it like `documentsArray = {};`

Comment: So i have to do this for my example documentsArray = DocumentModel in my method or where?

Comment: you can do when declaring or just before this line; 

```  this.documentsArray.filename = file.name  ```

Comment: I tried to do this but same error:       const documents = this.documentsArray
and then work with documents but still the same error I tried to this in the first line of my uploadFile method

Comment: it will throw the same error because this.documentsArray is undefined therefore documents is undefined. You should initialize it.